# Word 2007 problems auto advancing bullets

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

When working in a list - doesn't matter if its bulleted, numbered or multi-level - the next line of the list does not advance to the next bullet or number when I press ENTER.  The next line reverts to the Normal style and I have to manually convert it to a bulleted line either by copying the format from the previous line or by clicking on the bullet/number/multilevel list buttons on the Home bar.

I've searched Help and Microsoft's website for info thinking that perhaps there is an option that's either been turned on or off which is causing the problem, but I can't find anything.  If anyone has an answer I would greatly appreciate hearing from you.

Comment: How are you setting the formatting - I've tried a couple of ways and it works for me?

Comment: `Shift`+`Enter` moves to the next line, but indented as part of the current bullet/numbered item. Hitting `Enter` creates a new bullet or the next number in the list

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that in the paragraph formatting dialog foR the bullet style the "following paragraph" style is NOT set to "normal".

Each style can define a style for the following paragraph, which can result in the type of behavior you are seeing.